# Tennis Score Keeper

Tags: c++, function

I am willing to write a code of a tennis score keeper in *C++* that keeps track of the score, but there are 2 problems that occur when I run the program:

1. I can't quit the loop with while(cin!="q")
2. The functions wouldn't initialize the variables

   ```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<string>
   using namespace std;

   int points1=0, points2=0;
   int set1=0, set2=0;
   int games1=0, games2=0;
   string in="";
   void score(int point,int set,int game);
   int main()
   {

       do
       {
         cout<<"POINTS: "<<points1<<":"<<points2<<endl<<"SETS: "<<set1<<":"<<set2<<endl<<"GAMES: "<<games1<<":"<<games2<<endl;
         cout<<"Who scored - player 1 or player 2? (p1/p2) :  ";
         cin>>in;
         if(in=="p1")
         {
          void score(int points1,int set1,int games1);
         }
         else if(in=="p2")
         {
          void score(int points2,int set2,int games2);
         }
         else {cout<<endl<<"Error!"<<endl<<endl;}
         }
         while(cin!="q");



       system("pause");
           return 0;
      }

    void score(int& point,int& set,int& game){
     if(set<5)
     {
      switch(point)
      {
          case '30':
               point=point+10;
          case '40':
               set++;
               point=0;
          default:
               point=point+15;
         }
      }
      else game++;
   }
   ```

Comment: Your `score` prototype doesn't match function implementation. Also, the way you're passing arguments to the function is incorrect. It should be something more like `score(points1, set1, games1);`.

Comment: This should give linker errors as it is.  There are a lot of problems.  Your `score` _declaration_ doesn't have a matching _definition_.  When you call a function don't use the same syntax as a _declaration_, just pass the arguments (and optionally store the return value).  So, `score(points1, set1, games1);`.  Lot's of other incorrect things as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an infinite `while` loop with a `break`, also get rid of type defs in function calls -- something like:

```
while (true) {
    cin >> in;
    if (in == "p1") {
        score(points1, set1, games1);
    }
    else if (in == "p2") {
        score(points2, set2, games2);
    }
    else if (in == "q") {
        break;
    } else {
        cout << endl << "Error!" << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
while(cin!="q");
```

should be

```
while(in!="q");
```

In your function, your switch is on an integer value, so your cases should use an integer value as well:

```
case '30':
```

should be

```
case 30:
```

The others as well.

This is a function prototype:

```
void score(int points1,int set1,int games1);
```

This is a function call:

```
score(points1,set1,games1);
```

Make sure you have function calls where you want to execute the function. You have a lot of prototypes where they don't belong.

Some Tennis tips: you need to be two points ahead to win a set, two sets ahead to win a match. You may want to take that into account in your functions. Points and sets of a single player will not be enough to decide who won a set or game.

Edit:

In addition, if you want variables you pass to a function to change outside of this function, you need to pass them by reference.

```
 void score(int& points1, int& set1, int& games1);
```

Note the ampersands.

Passing parameters to a function will make a [b]copy[/b] of the parameters. This is refered to as pass-by-value, because the value is passed. You can pass-by-reference, which means you  don't create a copy but instead pass the location of the actual variable. Changes to it will then be reflected back to your main program.

Comment: It still doesn't work... The values of the variables won't change

Comment: Additionally when someone wins a game you need to reset their points as well as the other persons points.
Also in general having variables named var1, var2, ... means you've done it wrong and should be using an array, and having a set of variables repeated instead of multiple structs of those variables is a bad sign too.

Answer (score 1):

The following line is wrong: `while(cin!="q");`
Instead of `cin` you need to use `in!="q"`

The second issue is because you're calling the function in the wrong way.
When you call a function, you just write its name and pass the specified arguments, you don't need to write the function return type when calling it. Also you don't need to specify the types of the arguments you're passing. Your function call should be :

```
score(points2, set2, games2)
```

And finally you're switching on an integer, so your cases should check for integers.